# C# - How to install the Database in AppData directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've to install my window form application and keep the database in AppData directory. But I couldn't establish the proper path to the database in app.confing.I found some answer on StackOverflow and try the following.

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="Default" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
    (*.mdb)};AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\HamaraPaisa.mdb" 
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

And in my Program.cs file :

```
  static class Program
   {
      static void Main()
      {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", 
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
       Application.Run(new Form1());
      }
   }
```

But I still get the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" 
 exception because I'm not connected to Database.

Comment: Why are you using the ODBC driver for a Microsoft Acces database? Can't you use OleDb instead?

Comment: By default the database in windows are stored in temp folder. It would be stored in **C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Temp** in this directory and you would be able to find your database there. So you have to programmatically check and store database there only. It is recommended to store your database in this directory only because whenever your application gets uninstalled but your database still remains there.

Comment: Run this test on your machine. 1. Create a empty file using notepad and name it something.udl . 2. Double click it and it will open a wizard. 3. Now test your db connection by selecting the ODBC for Access database. Most probably you dont have ODBC for Access installed on your machine

Comment: @AnmolRathod I am very interested to know who is telling you to store your valuable data in a TEMP folder. A folder that, by its name, is just temporary and should be used only to store easily replaceable data and little else.

Comment: @Steve, I'm using odbc probably in case when user hasn't installed ms office Access on his machine.

Comment: If you are using an old MDB file (and a 32bit app) then you shouldn't have this worry. OleDb with JET.4.0 is available in every framework version and doesn't require Office installed

Comment: @Steve no one advised me about where to store your database but, in windows by default it gets stored in that particular directory. If you know how to change that default behavior than please share a link or code which demonstrate that thing. I have gone through this problem and i was ended up with its default settings only. Note this directory would also be containing database or other files of applications running on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ODBC driver to open a Microsoft Access Database then the correct connection string is

```
OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
                                         Dbq=|DataDirectory|\HamaraPaisa.mdb");
```

If you are using the OleDb libraries then you should write your connection string as

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;  
                                           Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HamaraPaisa.mdb");
```

or, if you have a 32bit application and an old (pre-access 2007) MDB file then you can use

```
 OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;  
                                            Data Source=|DataDirectory|\HamaraPaisa.mdb");
```

However I strongly suggest you to create your personal data folder inside the *Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData* and do not add another file to an already crowded folder.